# Node.js & avconv — real-time video conversion

Tags: node.js, avconv

I'm working on real-time video conversion demo app. Video file is parsed with `node-multiparty`, file's `part is piped` to `avconv.stdin` and when processed, the `chunk pipes` to `write stream`.

Here's a part of the source code:

```
var form = new multiparty.Form(),
    args = ['-i', 'pipe:0', '-f', 'webm', 'pipe:1'],
    avconv = spawn('avconv', args),
    output = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);

form.on('part', function (part) {
  if (part.filename) {
    part.pipe(avconv.stdin);

    part.on('end', function() {
      console.log('===== Video has been uploaded! =====');
      avconv.stdin.end();
    });
  }
});

avconv.stdout.pipe(output);
```

I'm interested in `end` event attached to file's `part`. Normally the event should be fired when a part is parsed, which means it has been uploaded.

I have a test video file (~800KB) and a low-level laptop for testing. While running a test on localhost, `end` event is firing at the very end of `avconv` conversion process, which lasts for ~15s.

800KB video file has been uploaded way faster, but it looks like the `part` stream is still not empty waiting for data to be processed by `avconv`.

Am I right or there's another thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely right.
The `Readable` stream emits `end` event only when it is totally consumed.
Have a look here: http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end